# Notice unread messages

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Im trying to notice the new unreaded messages on my chat. I'm using a bundle  and I create my own friendlist.Then on my chat view I can choice which user I want to chat with. I will show you my code cause I didn't get errors and I'm not sure why this don't work.

I got a column on my table called reading that works with a boolean and set a 0 if its an unread message.

***ChatController.php***

On my indexAction I made this :

```
` $userConnected= $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

    $friends= $em->getRepository(Agenda::class)->findByIdUsuari($userConnected);  

    $messages=  $em->getRepository(Messages::class)->findByAddressee($userConnected); 

    $newmessage= array();
    foreach ($messages as $value) {
        if ($value->getReading() == 0) {
            $newmessage= $value->getAuthor()->getId();
        }
     }
```

On my view I print the users and form.

That's where I print Users :

```
 <div id="selectUser">
        {% for user in users %}
            {% if user.id != currentUser.id %}              
                <a href="" onclick="return false;" data-number="{{ user.id }}" class="changeUser" >{{ user.username }}</a>
            {% endif %}          
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

How can I implement that if the User's id of my list are the same as I saved on my variable $newmessage ???. I want that if got the same id, that means that got a 0 and he don't read the message so if I can check that I'll implement a class that will change the color of user's name.

**UPDATE :**

It seems that didnt work cause it sets Reading value to 1 and I don't know why cause on AjaxController it sets on 0 when I Send the message and change to 1 when user read it.

Controller:

https://pastebin.com/6LZ1FVG2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you render your page inside your controller, you need to pass the variable into an array like this:

```
$this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
    'newmessage' => $newmessage,
));
```

After in your twig you can use `newmessage` variable like this for example

```
{% if user.id == newmessage %}
```

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't share what I render.


  return $this->render('BackEndBundle:Default:chat.html.twig', array(
            'chatForm' => $chatForm->createView(), 
            'users' => $users, 
            'friends' => $friends, 
            'newmessage' => $newmessage, 
            'getMessageUrl' => $getMessageUrl, 
            'currentUser' => $this->getUser()));
    }

Comment: so you can check inside twig your user.id with newmessage right?

Comment: Yes I tried to apply styles if user.id == newmessage but seems that didn't work.

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't work"? If you print newmessage what do you retrieve? Is the same of user.id?

Comment: It prints Array 0.

Comment: means that the script doesn't enter into the condition inside the foreach loop into the controller, the problem is into the condition if ($value->getReading() == 0)  or the array is empty before the foreach

Comment: Then how should  I get the Reading value of my entity?

Comment: Do you have inside your entity method getReading? if so print the content of getReading inside your foreach, maybe inside your database there isn't record with reading 0 value.

Comment: Yes, I check it . I got the method on my entity and when I make a Var_dump of the method it returns bool(true) .

Comment: true means that is 1 not 0 the value so it doesn't enter and not set $newmessage

Comment: I don't understand why sets 1 when the message is unreaded...
It seems that when i send the message sets 1 to reading at the moment.

Comment: This is another problem I think :)

Comment: I checked  the AjaxController and it sets the reading on false when User send the message so i don't understand why change to 1.

https://pastebin.com/6LZ1FVG2

Just when swap the user sets to 1 but if  I don't swap I don't know why now its 1.

Comment: I don't know exactly the logic but this is another question, you can open a new question for this and I can check the new problem. :) It's important to view the entity message, try to put instead of false value 0 for example

Comment: Okk I'll do it . Thanks for your help.

Comment: perfect, close this question and reopen another to help other people to similar problem. I hope to help you into the new question

Comment: It seems that i need to wait 90 min to post another question :(

Comment: Redirecting question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377972/reading-value-on-chat-messages